# AS3 Compiler error 1083: problem with else syntax

Tags: actionscript-3

Can anyone help me with finding the error here. Its for my loading bar at the begging of my flash movie.

```
if (_root.getBytesLoaded() == _root.getBytesTotal()); 
{
    gotoAndPlay(4)
}

else
{
    gotoAndPlay(1)
}
```

Comment: lose the _root and make it root This is AS3 correct?

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (_root.getBytesLoaded() == _root.getBytesTotal()); { gotoAndPlay(4) }
```

should be

```
if (_root.getBytesLoaded() == _root.getBytesTotal()) { gotoAndPlay(4) }
```

You are terminating your if statement with that `;`

Comment: oh sorry. Loosing the ; didn't do it

Comment: 1120: access of underfined property _root

Comment: You have to change your settings to publish to ActionScript 2, not ActionScript 3.

Comment: `_root` suspiciously looked like AS2 to me too, that was going to be my first question.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon on the first row is ending your statement prematurely, you need to drop it:

```
if (_root.getBytesLoaded() == _root.getBytesTotal())
{
    gotoAndPlay(4);
}
else
{
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Also, it's good practice to always end your lines with a semicolon, it shouldn't matter here, but always do it just to be safe.